# How to customize a set of controls with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have this structure for fill out forms in html

```
    <fieldset class="signup">
        <div>
            <label>First Name:</label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Last Name:</label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server"/>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
```

And I defined this CSS

```
form fieldset 
{
    clear: both;
    border-width: 0px;
    border-style: none none none none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

form fieldset div 
{
    clear: left;
    display: block;
    margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    vertical-align: central;
}

form fieldset div label {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    /*width: 150px;*/
    padding: 1px 20px 0px 0px;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: central;
}
```

The appareance is clean but I commented the width attribute in the last style for labels in order to make it generic in the future. So I added a new style for my specific form and added this class to the fieldset but it's not working. I lost the width of my labels so how can I fix this mistake?

```
form fieldset div label .signup {
    width: 150px;
}
```

Comment: There are no elements with a class of `signup` inside a label, so no width is being applied to `.signup`. I believe you probably just want `.signup { width: 150px; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
fieldset.signup div label  {
    width: 150px;
}
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks. I'm gonna accept it in some minutes because the page does not allow me to do it now!

Answer (score 3):

Your selector is incorrect. What you want is likely:

```
form fieldset.signup div label {
    width: 150px;
}
```

On a side note, I suggest reading up on CSS Selectors to understand the syntax a bit more. See:

1. [Selectors Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/)
2. [MDN (Selectors)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors)
3. [MSDN (Understanding CSS Selectors)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh781510%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
min-width: 150px !important;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a long chain of descendant CSS selectors and there is no such hierarchy in your Document. Use comma to group selectors. White space means descendant. also, Use > to indicate direct child its more efficient than descendant.